# How can I use JS to simulate the event of clicking a link in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

How can I use JS to simulate the event of clicking a link in Chrome?

I want the effect of autoclick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "simulate".

If you want to change page url,

```
window.location.href = document.getElementById("yourAHref").href;
```

or with jQuery:

```
window.location.href = $('yourAnchorSelector').attr('href');
```

If you want to simulate the clicking of the event, you will have to use [`fireEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536423(VS.85).aspx) or [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent), depending on the browser:

jQuery makes this easy by:

```
$('yourAnchorSelector').trigger('click');
```

But will only trigger events that have been bound through jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/click/):

```
$("a").click();
```

Will click all anchors on the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by
Simply writing this.

```
document.getElementById("yourLinkID").onclick()
```

Here is another way to do that.

```
var fireOnThis = document.getElementById('someID');
var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evObj.initMouseEvent( 'click', true, true, window, 1, 12, 345, 7, 220, false, false, true, false, 0, null );
fireOnThis.dispatchEvent(evObj);
```

For more details search "Manually firing events" in [This](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents) article .

Comment: This will not work in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari. Only IE will work.